# What AWS IAM permissions are needed for using the bottlenose API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bottlenose

I want to use the [bottlenose](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose) API for building a price predictor for Amazon products. I understand that it's a wrapper. I have these questions:

1. Is it must to have the AWS Associate Tag to use bottlenose? Or can I query the product prices and such using only the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key?
2. While creating a user in AWS IAM, what permissions do I need to give it so that he is able to use the Bottlenose API programmatically?

Comment: AWS AMI?  Perhaps you mean IAM?

Comment: Oops, right I meant IAM. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

A policy something like below. (note, the version must be 2012-10-17 not a current date)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ProductAdvertisingAPI:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```